# Cannot deserialize response into a class in RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm trying to obtain an ArrayList of object and initialize it in a wrapper class,

this is my request;

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
 Inventory i = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8082/items",Inventory.class);
```

my response handler;

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/items", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
 public ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
 return ItemList.getItemList();
 }
```

my ItemList class,

```
public class ItemList{
//to keep a list of globally available list of orders with the type Item.class objects
private static ArrayList<Item> itemList;

public static ArrayList<Item> getItemList() {
    return itemList;
}

public static void setItemList(ArrayList<Item> itemList) {
    ItemList.itemList = itemList;
}

public static Item getItemById(String id) throws NoSuchItem {
    ArrayList<Item> temp = ItemList.getItemList();
    for(Item x:temp){
         if(x.getId().equals(id))
          return x;
     }
     throw new NoSuchItem();
}
};
```

My Inventory class,

```
public class Inventory{

private ArrayList<Item> itemList;

public ArrayList<Item> getRandomList(int size) {
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    ArrayList<Item> temp = this.itemList;
    if(size>=itemList.size()){
        return itemList;
    }
    else{
      Random rand = new Random();      
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        int j = rand.nextInt(temp.size());
        Item random = temp.get(j);
        random.generateQuantity();
        items.add(random);
        temp.remove(random);
      }
    }
    return items;

}

public ArrayList<Item> getItemList() {
    return itemList;
}

public void setItemList(ArrayList<Item> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
}


};
```

and finally my Item class,

```
public class Item {
private String  name ;
private String  supplier ;
private String   weight;
private String   id ;
private String   location = "not assigned" ;
private int quantity;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSupplier() {
    return supplier;
}

public void setSupplier(String supplier) {
    this.supplier = supplier;
}

public String getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(String weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void generateQuantity(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int i = rand.nextInt(100);
    if(i<3){
        this.quantity = 3;
    }
    else if(i<33){
        this.quantity = 2;    
    }
    else{
        this.quantity = 1;
    }
    }
    };
```

I'm building a microservice project using springboot, my response and ItemList class exist in one service , request and Inventory in the next service and the Item class on both the services, But when i run the method i get an JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `ServiceA.Inventory` out of START_ARRAY token, What am i doing wrong here?

PS - a sample response the /items endpoint returns ,

```
[
{
    "name": "Mars",
    "supplier": "Nestle",
    "weight": "1",
    "id": "mars",
    "location": "not asssigned"
},
{
    "name": "Kit Kat",
    "supplier": "Nestle",
    "weight": "1",
    "id": "kitkat",
    "location": "not asssigned"
},
{
    "name": "Double Decker",
    "supplier": "Nestle",
    "weight": "1",
    "id": "dd",
    "location": "not asssigned"
}
]
```

Comment: What do you get when you call `http://localhost:8082/items`? An example of JSON it returns might be helpful.

Comment: updated it in the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to yout JSON there is no `Inventory` in the response. So when you do this:

```
Inventory i = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8082/items", Inventory.class);
```

it complains because your response actually has an array (or list) of `Item`. Object inventory cannot be instantiated from an arrray. Try this:

```
Item[] items = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8082/items", Item[].class);
```

and it should work.

To have class `Inventory` deserialized your JSON response should be something like:

```
{
    itemList: [
        {
            "name": "Mars",
            "supplier": "Nestle",
            "weight": "1",
            "id": "mars",
            "location": "not asssigned"
        },
    ...
    ]
}
```

**But note**: There is also a problem with your `ItemList`. Anyway that is another topic because you should first think whhether your response JSON is ok or not.

Comment: Thankyou so much, You're right i overlooked the fact that my response only sends an array of items, not and itemList object, which i probably is what you mean by the problem in ItemList class if im not wrong?

Comment: @AshenJayawardena Actually I first a bit misunderstood the purpose of `ItemList`. But instead of using static you could made it component/service - say `ItemService`- (which by default are singletons in Spring) and inject it where needed.

Comment: well i need to call the request every 5 seconds and update my inventory constantly, I'm building a simulation, by an ItemService class im assuming it's to pass the data upon creation only? since even the itemList array gets updated every 5 seconds it's kind of tough to get around, I'm sorry if i misunderstood what you were saying, this is my very first microservices project :)

Comment: Once injected you can update the list in injected component like `ItemService.updateItemList(itemList)`. Static stuff might pose some problems later, like if you need to mock stuff in tests or so. Or even so that `ItemService` updates it all by itself with `@Scheduled` and provides only a customized getter for items in that list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a no args constructor to the Item class.